# How to align background image outside of div?

Tags: css

I know how to align my background image as well as my #wrapper div tag, but I am unable to get them to line up the way I want. Here is the example:

http://www.marathoneindhoven.nl/

The blue runner stays locked to the main div tag when resizing the window. If I add a large #container around the whole #wrapper, when I resize the browser I have a big space on the left side of the screen because the overall width of the #container is still trying to center itself. I have tried using the css property overflow but can not seem to get that to work either.

How can I possibly get this to work??

Comment: You'll be better off including some sample code here in your post. Most of the people here at SO don't want to visit your site and dig for the code they need. You'll get a much better and faster response by including the code here.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. What do you want to happen to the blue runner instead of what currently is happening?

Comment: Can you give us a link to what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blue runner to move with the page then change your css to this:

```
#wrapper {
     background: url(/images/bg-runner.png) right 0 top 150px no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to accomplish what is happening on the given link, all my code makes the background image stick to the right side and the given example moves with the content

Comment: The link you provided is not your site? or the site you need fixing?

Comment: no the site i provided is not my site. it has the desired effect with the blue runner silhouette.